# CSS issues Nav Buttons

Tags: css, list, html-lists

Hi I have some CSS issues
My problem is that my nav bar buttons are changing simply by moving the CSS code in the style sheet.
I also cant seem to get my border-right to work only on the  :firstchild as it count to both first and lastchild
Here is an example of my issue with the style sheet code blocks moving that's affecting the results.

All the same code but different output:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyF3m/6/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/PsX27/

and I also recieve the following error with making my border-right work on the :firstchild (only)

[image: The successful Result]

[image: The failed result]

As mentioned I do have

```
li:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    top: 10px;
}

li:first-child {
    padding: 37px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    right: 25px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-right: #525252 1px solid;
}
```

but it appears that it isn't working on this page.

Comment: Either way, your HTML is invalid...the only permitted **direct** children of a `ul` are `li`. Put the anchor links INSIDE the `li`

Comment: The first fiddle seems to have two rules for `li:first-child` with almost equal declaration blocks whereas the second fiddle has a `li:last-child` rule. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I just noticed and no its still the same issue,
updated - http://jsfiddle.net/kyF3m/6/

Comment: @ByronMcGrath take note of what Paulie_D has said about `ul` and `li` as what you've done is really rather wrong.

Comment: The updated fiddle's CSS still doesn't match the CSS of the second one; the `li:last-child` rules contain totally different declarations.

Comment: Making them identical wouldn't work because they are different sizes, sorry but please can you refer to the actual issue as I need to get that sorted priority instead of some silly html error that in this instance doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: I've seen what he said and I've tested it also and it made no difference at all btw

Comment: @BryonMcGrath no but your original code was not correct html. You cannot wrap an anchor around a list element. The `a` must go inside the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure was itself. you cannot use a `a` directly under `ul`. i have changed the approach a bit but the desired output has been achieved and will not change in any condition.

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsX27/50/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="Nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="ReviewPage.aspx">Review</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#.aspx">Your Reviews</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-indent:0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
}
#Nav {
    height: 45px;
    width: 240px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #242424;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color: #808080;
    padding:11px 21px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-right: #525252 1px solid;
}

li:last-child a{
    border-right:none;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #20a7b0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="ReviewPage.aspx">Review</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.aspx">Your Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
#wrapper > ul{
    display: inline-block; /*Size to content*/
    height: 45px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #242424;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    padding: 0; /*essential*/

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
#wrapper > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-right: #525252 1px solid;
}



#wrapper > ul > li:last-child {
        border-right: 0px;
}
#wrapper > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: #20a7b0;
}
```

What you looking for?

EDIT:

```
#wrapper > ul > li > a{
    color: #808080;
}
```

I forgot this, sry

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li{border-right:1px solid #ddd !important;}
```

```html
<b>just apply these css n your code. take the main class of navigation and apply these css</b>
```